# excel macro - new row copy

Tags: excel, schedule, vba

Been searching around for a while now without any answer.
I'm creating an automatic schedule that calculates working hours and so forth for my employees.
Instead of creating new rows at the bottom of the table manually, putting in all the funktions and style the cells with specific formats I want a macro to do this.

I have created a macro but, the problem is that everytime it is executed, it starts of course from the place where I created it in the first place.

So, the macro should somehow search for the last place in the table. Copy the two last and create new ones including the if-statements, cell format and styling.

The second macro I need to create is a toggle function where the macro searches for the rows that containts the working hour (underneath the times) and hides or unhides the rows. Is that possible?

I really hope that someone can help me! Thanks!
 /Martin

Screenshot: http://www.martinhult.se/screenshot.jpg

Comment: Can you provide the code for your first macro? Also the if-statements too would be cool

Answer (score 0):

Would be better if you can share your first macro (which I believe is recorded?).

But essentially you want to use something like "activesheet.usedrange.rows.count" to see how many rows have already been used and then start at used rows + 1.

Comment: The thing is that I don't have any programming skills in VB at all .. so, kind of hard for me.. there's the file.